# Add line return to a block of text, but don't break words

Tags: python, string, line

I have a long string like:

```
mystring = 'It was the best of times, it was the worst of times, it was the age of wisdom, it was the age of foolishness...'''
```

And I'd like to insert a linebreak every 20 letters.  Except I don't want to split a word in half, so if it splits at 22 letters, that's fine.  Does anyone know of an intelligent solution to this?

Comment: Python has a built in library for this called [textwrap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [textwrap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html):

```
>>> mystring = 'It was the best of times, it was the worst of times, it was the age of wisdom, it was the age of foolishness...'''
>>> import textwrap
>>> textwrap.wrap(mystring, width=20)
['It was the best of', 'times, it was the', 'worst of times, it', 'was the age of', 'wisdom, it was the', 'age of', 'foolishness...']
```